# How to reference a .json file in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet

I am trying to add a `.json` vector layer to a Leaflet.js map, [viewable here via GitHub page](https://aaronkyle.github.io/concept/web-gis/sandbox/leaflet-test.html), with [source code here](https://github.com/aaronkyle/concept/blob/gh-pages/web-gis/sandbox/leaflet-test.html).

Here's a shortened version of the file for reference (the GitHub page linked above shows it working in context).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">


  <!-- LEAFLET-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin="" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-nMMmRyTVoLYqjP9hrbed9S+FzjZHW5gY1TWCHA5ckwXZBadntCNs8kEqAWdrb9O7rxbCaA4lKTIWjDXZxflOcA==" crossorigin=""></script>

  <style>
    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #map {
      width: 600px;
      height: 600px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id='map'></div>

  <script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([-7.08, -78.5565467], 12);
    let osmLayer = L.tileLayer('https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png', {
      attribution: 'Wikimedia maps beta | &copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);
    let marker = L.marker([-7.2861634, -78.579712])
      .addTo(map);
    let marker2 = L.marker([-7.1605494, -78.5392218])
      .addTo(map);
    ///let test_L = L.geoJSON("test.json", {
    ///weight: 2,
    /// color: '#100'
    ///}).addTo(map);
    //let layerGroup = L.geoJSON(watersheds, {
    // onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    //layer.bindPopup('</h1><p>name: '+feature.properties.WTSHNAME+'</p>');
    //  }
    // }).addTo(map);
    //street layer using mapbox basic
    // Changed to OSM just to avoid the token requirement, for the purpose of demo.
    var mapboxbasic = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.wmflabs.org/bw-mapnik/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      zIndex: 1
    });
    //aerial layer using mapbox satellite
    // Changed to OSM just to avoid the token requirement, for the purpose of demo.
    var mapboxsat = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      maxZoom: 18,
      zIndex: 2
    });
    var Esri_WorldImagery = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
      attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
    });
    var basemap = {
      'Streets': mapboxbasic,
      'Aerials': mapboxsat,
      'ESRI Imagery': Esri_WorldImagery
    } // Refer to the individual Tile Layers only. They will go into the tilePane.
    ;
    L.control.layers(basemap).addTo(map); // Layers Control just to switch between the 2 basemaps.
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

The code (with the errant sections commented out)  successfully add in markers using lat long coordinates, but my code breaks when I try to reference the `.json` file. [By 'breaks', I mean that the base layer selection panel in the top right corner disappears and the vector layer is not added.]

The `.json` file is called in using `<script src="test.json" type="text/javascript"></script>` [with the `.json` file [hosted on GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aaronkyle/concept/gh-pages/web-gis/sandbox/test.json)]

The code I have tried is:

```
    let test_L = L.geoJSON(test, {
        weight: 2,
        color: '#100'
      }).addTo(map);
```

Following the official example at: https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/

And :

```
   $.getJSON("test.json",function(data){
   L.geoJson(data).addTo(newMap);
   });
```

Following the discussions [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570930/displaying-json-files-in-leaflet), on [this forum](https://www.igismap.com/add-load-geojson-file-point-polyline-polygon-map-leaflet-js/), and as modelled [with this gist](https://gist.github.com/mollietaylor/7582459) -- all to no avail.

I am clearly missing something, but I don't understand what.

For comparison, I managed to get [this example working on Observable](https://beta.observablehq.com/d/ca447e3d21c9bbda).

Can anyone help to point me in the right direction? I'd really appreciate it!!

Thanks in advance for your time and guidance,

Aaron

Comment: `<script src="test.json" type="text/javascript">` — This is nonsense. JSON is not JavaScript.

Comment: `$.getJSON("(test.json"` — This looks like you just made a typo and added a `(` to the URL.

Comment: If the typo isn't the problem, then there isn't much we can say given the information you've provided. Do some debugging. Use the developer tools in your browser. Check the network tab to see if the data is being fetched correctly. Add console.log statements to see if functions are being run and if the data looks the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks Quentin!  I tried referencing in the `.json` file with `<script scr="">` following the official example, but I see now that their 'geoJSON' file is actually a JS file (called in with `<script src="sample-geojson.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`).  I am still learning here (very much a newbie).

Comment: Thank you again, Quentin.  I checked and the typo does not appear to be the problem.  I'll try to look into the developer tools.  I provided the link to my code on GitHub, but can add the full code in here (with the problematic sections commented out).  I suspect the issue is indeed with fetching the data.  I am not sure how to resolve.

Comment: You mentioned using the URL to the github .json file. How are you setting the url in $.getJSON? Or is it internal and on the same level as the html file?

Comment: Hi @CodeMonkey, and thanks for your help!  It doesn't work as either an absolute URL:

`$.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aaronkyle/concept/gh-pages/web-gis/sandbox/test.json",function(data){
  L.geoJson(data).addTo(newMap);
  });`

.. or as an abbreviated URL:

`$.getJSON("test.json",function(data){
  L.geoJson(data).addTo(newMap);
  });`

The file is sitting in the same directory and [on the same level as the HTML file](https://github.com/aaronkyle/concept/tree/gh-pages/web-gis/sandbox).

Comment: @aaron.kyle — See my previous comment about debugging. You need to narrow down where the problem is.

Comment: One thing that can help with debugging is moving the script code into a `.js` file. That way you can utilize the the debugger in browsers.

Comment: @CodeMonkey - the debugger does work with inline `<script>` elements.

Comment: So it seems. Never knew. Still, good practice to put the scripts in `.js` files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @CodeMonkey for the leads on this answer:

This guidance on loading in `.json` files from other forum posts was good, the code

```
   $.getJSON("test.json",function(data){
   L.geoJson(data).addTo(newMap);
   });
```

is appropriate for calling in the JSON data.  My mistake, as @CodeMonkey notes, is that I used `map` as the id / name for the function, but the examples were adding data to `newMap`, which didn't exist in my example.

Also, to get this working properly, I needed to add in JQuery to my HTML file, so adding:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

into the `<head>` section.

The code now works:

https://aaronkyle.github.io/concept/web-gis/sandbox/leaflet-test.html

Awesome.

Thanks to everyone for helping me to work though this question!!

Answer (score 0):

So first thing that I noticed was that the github link you have for the raw of the `.json` file is not working. Probably a github issue.

I mention that because you were trying to get it to use. in jQuery, when using a URL on a remote host, you have to add at the end `?callback=?` to get it to use JSONP instead. [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12990586/2112501)

Moving on, to reference the `.json` file, you need to use the path in relative format. If the `.json` file is in the same directory as the `.html` file, then it should work. If it is down a level, then you would do `/down/test.json` as the path.

I was able to replicate part of your code into a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sunrlluNWBQVIfxOuZ1P)

I think the issue was you were trying to set the `.json` points to `newMap` which does not exist.

Comment: "when using a URL on a remote host, you have to add at the end ?callback=? to get it to use JSONP" — (1) It isn't on a remote host. The OP said they were in the same folder. (2) JSONP (a) only works if the data is in JSONP format and (b) is a horrible hack that was superceded years ago by CORS.

Comment: This is the OP's quoted code: `$.getJSON("test.json"`. That is a relative URL.

Comment: Did you even read? He mention that he tried using the link of it via GitHub. I am working on what I know and can gather from the OP and other places. I went on to point out that his code was setting to `newMap`, not `map`, which I believe is the issue, unless the OP was mistaken or was trying something not shown. I only pointed out the relative path part because the OP seemed confused or not well informed on how it worked, since he is, as he said, "very much a newbie". Perhaps he did know about, but perhaps not.

Comment: *"when using a URL on a remote host, you have to add at the end ?callback=? to get it to use JSONP instead"* only works the remote host supports JSONP. It's not a silver bullet to access any kind of remote resource.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for helping me through this! I am still working to figure out how to use the debugging tools per @Quentin 's guidance, but haven't yet found a solution.  To get around any CORS issues, I tried using rawgit.com, and therefore substituted the relative path `test.json` with https://cdn.rawgit.com/aaronkyle/concept/gh-pages/web-gis/sandbox/test.json, but this didn't get me through it.  As @Quentin noted, the issue does seem to have to do with the `.json` file not being appropriately "loaded" (for lack of a better term), but I still don't get why or how to correct.

Comment: Console log the data when it comes out of the jQuery. And see what it is. If it is not what you expected then you have narrowed it down.

Comment: Thanks @CodeMonkey.  Honestly I am not so good yet with these console logs, but am trying....  More soon (though I am surprised this is such an active discussion and challenging issues; seems there's just something simple I'm missing regarding how to call in the json data using Leaflet.js).